# Setting a default time to a bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

Im using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker and I want to have it set to a default time lets say 8:00. I read the documentation and I dont see anything about setting up a default time, the only thing i see in there is to set up a default date:

> defaultDate:"",                 //sets a default date, accepts js
>   dates, strings and moment objects

Its really important I can get it to a default time because I have it set up to go up by increments of 15 minutes and the way it currently works is by using the current time so for example the default time would be like 18:41 so then i can only have times by increments of 15 for that so I couldnt have 20:00. If anyone is familiar with this plugin it would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date object in javascript obtain can contains date and time. So set default date to a new Date object where you set hours and minutes.

```
pickDate: false,
defaultDate: new Date(1979, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0),
// new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? Im using simply the timepicker I dont want the date so I think like example 4 on the documentaion

Comment: If you only want time, set pickDate to false. But defaultDate takes a Date Javascript object as value, and javascript Date object are created this way. I think you can set whatever value in year, month and day, timepicker will ignore it.

Comment: I added defaultDate: new Date(79, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0);  now when I click the icon the widget isnt showing up anymore

Comment: Sorry, this is not a semicolon but a comma. Can you try again ?